# Procyon Libraries with AVR Studio 6

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc

I am having a problem using the Procyon libraries with AVR Studio 6. For now I am attempting to use the timer.h library.

I have included the Procyon file as a directory by including it in AVRProject Properties/toolchain/Compiler/Directories.

So I have a project, and i include the timer.h and global.h files. Since doing the above step errors about missing include files have stopped.

Now I am finding that the compiler doesn't recognize any of the functions from timer.h, ie `setPWMAon()` etc.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a tutorial showing successful set up and use of Procyon libraries with AVR Studio 6?

**EDIT:** I have also tried to include the header files individually and have them in the file path. But then i get a bunch of errors about the macros in the libraries saying they are poisoned. As well as some undefined variables.

Comment: Feel free to up-vote while viewing this question so it might draw the attention of some people who know about AVR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding the directory with the header files you want to use, into the directory of your project,and then call it into your program like this?

```
#include "(name_of_dir_with_header_files)/timer.h"
```

Comment: I did try that, but there were some odd errors about the macros that procyon uses and they come up with some sort of `has been poisoned` error (means they have been deprecated by gcc)

Comment: Did you put all of the header files or just the ones you wanted?If you did the second one try putting everything in!Because the header file has probably dependencies on the other files in the same folder,and cannot work alone.

Comment: Yes we put all the headers in, we fixed all the dependencies but then there were weird compile errors. I have made an edit on the question.

Answer (score 0):

i do also have problem with timer library i think these libraries are not compatible with Atmel studio 6 
i had the same problem with LCD library that was written by MR.Pascal So i changed the lib and it works properly 
i suggest that you change the timer library 
if you found the library let us know i'm searching too